# link_to hardcoded absolute url without http in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to link to a url that doesn't start with `http`.

`link_to` works fine with an absolute url starting with `http`, but not without.

How can I get a link to a url without `http` at the start.

For example `www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5117345/absolute-urls-with-link-to-ruby-on-rails` (no http) or `stackoverflow.com/questions/5117345/absolute-urls-with-link-to-ruby-on-rails` (no www nor http)

Note: looks like the same question was [asked in forums](https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/link-to-external-site-without-http-in-url/91408)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want protocol-relative URLs?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Protocol-relative_URL

Example:

```
<%= link_to "test", '//www.stackoverflow.com/' %>
```